# Как правильно использовать "Buzzer" на C?

Tags: c, ассемблер, микроконтроллеры, avr

Всем добрый день.

У меня есть "assembly" код, который заставляет "Piezo" издавать звук. Вопрос мой заключается в том, что мог бы кто то объяснить на языке "C" так сказать ? (AT90USB647)

```
    // Datasheet-->PB6 ( PORTB , 6 bit )
    LDI R16, 0b01000000
    LDI R18, 0
    OUT 0x04, R16 ;DDRB
    start:
    EOR R18, R16
    OUT 0x05, R18 ;PORTB
    LDI R17, 0xFF
    delay_loop:
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        DEC R17
    BRNE delay_loop
    rjmp start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный код ничем не отличается от обычной "мигалки". Дословный перевод на языке Си:

```
int main()
{
    DDRB = 0b01000000;  // Настраиваем шестой PORTB на выход

    while(1){
        // Исключающее или (каждую итерацию цикла 6ой порт будет менять своё значение (0 или 1))
        PORTB ^= 0b01000000;
        // Тот регистр R17 (255)    
        char delay_cnt = 0xFF;
        // Цикл задержки (можно заменить _delay_us(время))
        while(delay_cnt){
            // Задержка в 6 тактов (время зависит от частоты МК), повторяющаяся 255 раз
            --delay_cnt;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: только следует помнить, что IRL компилятор этот цикл выкинет к чертям ;)... на практике следует использовать готовые обёртки, для gcc-avr/avr-libc — это `_delay_loop_1`, `_delay_loop_2`, `_delay_us`, `_delay_ms`.